# Vue Js filters not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having achieving a data set through `axios` which I'm trying to display in `VueJs`, Following is the data set:

```
{
"model":[
    {
        "id":2,
        "company_id":5,
        "salutation":"Mr",
        "first_name":"Check",
        "last_name":"Contact",
        "number":"234567890",
        "email":"check@contact.com",
        "alt_email":null,
        "address":"Thane",
        "city":"Thane",
        "state":"Maharastra",
        "country":"India",
        "profile":"Research-Corporate Access",
        "sectors_interested":"[\"Infrastructure\",\"Financial Services\",\"Capital Goods\",\"Pharmaceuticals\",\"Real Estate\"]",
        "companies_interested":"[{\"value\":7,\"label\":\"Test Company 4\"}]",
        "created_at":"2017-06-02 19:32:30",
        "updated_at":"2017-06-02 19:32:30",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "company":{
            "id":5,
            "name":"Test Company 3",
            "address":"Andheri",
            "city":"Mumbai",
            "state":null,
            "country":"India",
            "type":"Research-Tier II",
            "is_client":0,
            "created_at":"2017-06-02 14:48:20",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-02 14:48:20",
            "deleted_at":null
        }
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "company_id":4,
        "salutation":"Mr",
        "first_name":"Check 1",
        "last_name":"Contact",
        "number":null,
        "email":"check1@contact.com",
        "alt_email":null,
        "address":null,
        "city":null,
        "state":null,
        "country":null,
        "profile":"Investor-Research Head",
        "sectors_interested":"[\"Economics\",\"Real Estate\",\"Auto\",\"Consumer\",\"Logistics\",\"Oil & Gas\",\"Industrial\",\"Capital Goods\"]",
        "companies_interested":"[{\"value\":7,\"label\":\"Test Company 4\"},{\"value\":8,\"label\":\"Test Company 5\"}]",
        "created_at":"2017-06-03 06:28:03",
        "updated_at":"2017-06-03 06:28:03",
        "deleted_at":null,
        "company":{
            "id":4,
            "name":"Test Company 2",
            "address":"Chennai",
            "city":"Chennai",
            "state":null,
            "country":"India",
            "type":"Investor-Mutual Fund",
            "is_client":0,
            "created_at":"2017-06-02 06:42:16",
            "updated_at":"2017-06-02 15:32:17",
            "deleted_at":null
        }
    },
]
}
```

So basically I'm getting this data set and trying to have filter in this, I defined the data set as `model: {}` in `data()` and I'm having a method as `fetchContactData()` which sets the data into `model` now after getting the response when I `console.log(this.model)` I get the object set like this:

[image]

but for filtering the data set is not getting:

I've my filter functions in `computed` property

```
contacts: function() {
    if(this.model)
    {
        return this.model
             .filter(f => (f.company.is_client == 0))
            .map(d => ({label: d.name, value: d.id}))
    }
},
```

But here this.model is not working I'm getting error of this

> Error in render function: "TypeError: this.model.filter is not a function"

When I do `console.log(this.model)` before if statement, I get this:

[image]

If I do `console.log(this)` I can see the desired value being placed in model[!

[image]

Comment: If you do `console.log(this)` instead, is it what you expect?

Comment: @connexo Yes I can see model element having desired value. I've updated the question also with the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize the component, you set model to an object.

> I defined the data set as model: {} in data()

Objects do not have a `filter` method. Instead, initialize the `model` to an empty array.

```
data(){
    return {
        model: []
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting `Error in getter for watcher "filteredOptions": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"`

Comment: What's the `filteredOptions` watcher?

Comment: I've nothing in name of `filteredOptions` no methods, no watcher. I don't know from where it is coming.

Comment: Might be I'm using VSelect, from there its coming and I'm placing these filtered options in that.

Comment: Can you come to chat?

Comment: It is coming from VSelect as it is referencing there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145787/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-bert-evans).

Comment: @NitishKumar Where is no `name` property on the model objects. So in your `map` you need to get `.map(d => ({label: d.company.name, value: d.company.id}))`.

Comment: But I want the parent name as label and filter through model.company.is_client.

Comment: **There is no `name` property on the parent.**

Comment: Ohh found the mistake. Thanks.